# How to add all row elements in database to JSON object

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, object

I'm trying to retrieve all elements in database and display in webpage.But with my code it able to retrieve only one row element. Problem is, it retrieves all element but it adds the last row element to the object. I think all elements retrieved first are overwritten Because of that it displays last row element. Can anyone tell me how add all row elements to the JSON object. Please help me.

code :

```
            while(rs.next()){
                ImageFile.setName(rs.getString("imagename").trim());
                ImageFile.setDisc(rs.getString("imagedisc").trim());
                ImageFile.setImageid(rs.getInt("imageid"));
                ImageFile.setalbumid(rs.getInt("albumid"));

                byte imageData[] = rs.getBytes("imagethumb");
                String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageData);
                ImageFile.setThumb(encoded);

                byte image1Data[] = rs.getBytes("imagethumb");
                String encoded1 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(image1Data);

                ImageFile.setFull(encoded1);
            }
```

**The complete source code is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777159/retrieving-images-using-jquery-and-servlet-produces-http-status-500-error) question**

Please help me........Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list `Collection` to keep all the `row-values` of db, like - `List<ImageFileInfo>` which denotes List containing of `ImageFileInfo` Objects . And then serialize the list to `json String`.

```
List<ImageFileInfo> imageFileList = new ArrayList<ImageFileInfo>();
while(rs.next()){
    ImageFileInfo info = new ImageFileInfo();
    info..setName(rs.getString("imagename").trim());
    ...
    imageFileList.add(info);
}
```

Json serialization -

```
Type typeOfList= new TypeToken<List<ImageFileInfo>>(){}.getType();
String s = gson.toJson(imageFileList , typeOfList);
```

Comment: Is it `ArrayList<ImageFileInfo> imageFileList = new ArrayList<ImageFileInfo>();` or `List<ImageFileInfo> imageFileList = new ArrayList<ImageFileInfo>();` <- this was showing error. Tell me just confused  Thanks...

Comment: Error is `The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <ImageFileInfo>` if i remove arguments. Then tells to change it to `ArrayList<ImageFileInfo> imageFileList = new ArrayList<ImageFileInfo>();`

Comment: Seems to be very funny :) because same syntax working here(`List<ImageFileInfo> imageFileList = new ArrayList<ImageFileInfo>();`) And you can use suggested way.

Comment: Sorry sir, Now the servlet producing the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
 skypark.RetriveIm.doGet(RetriveIm.java:64)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)` What this means...

Comment: In firebug the response received from the server is `{"success":true,"imageInfo":[]}` is this means imageInfo is null. The image is not displaying. I'm struggling with this ....