# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception In tomcat7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

I'm trying to retrieve all elements in database and display in webpage.But now it was producing the error `HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this error. Please help me.

Stack Trace :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
   root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonObject
skypark.RetriveIm.doGet(RetriveIm.java:64)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
  root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
skypark.RetriveIm.doGet(RetriveIm.java:64)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**The complete source code is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777159/retrieving-images-using-jquery-and-servlet-produces-http-status-500-error) question**

This is the `#64` line `Gson gson=new Gson();`
Please help me........Thanks....

Comment: The exception stack trace itself indicates what the hell is going on under the hood - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonObject`.

Comment: How do you install/deploy the servlet code in the tomcat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *compiling* against the jar providing `com.google.gson.JsonObject` (or a dependent) but not *deploying* it at runtime. It needs to be deployed such that that class can be found/loaded by the classloader when run against.

Comment: I have added gson 2.2 jar file  in my project library. Please tell me then why this showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add library for Gson to you classpath. Either to your webapp (WEB-INF/lib) or to the classpath of your AS.

Comment: I have added gson 2.2 jar file  in my project library. Please tell me then why this showing the error.

Comment: Check the content of the jar if the class `com/google/gson/JsonObject` is there. If not download some other version, where it is for instance 2.1 (http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.1/gson-2.1-sources.jar!/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java?format=ok).

Comment: btw. what do you mean by "adding the jar to the project library"? You have to add it to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory in the war file or the the common lib path for Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using Eclipse and the project configured as Dynamic Web Project Right click on your project --> choose `configure build path` --> now `click on add jars button` --> and `select the Gson jar` --> click`OK`.

`Republish` the project and `restart` the server.

Else add the jar to `WEB-INF\lib directory`inside the war

Or directly into the Deployed location in the tomcat , but in the same directory as mentioned